# How can I get <linux/bootmem.h> fileand fix the error "fatal error: linux/bootmem.h: No such file or directory #include <linux/bootmem.h>"?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am going to run a code which uses `#include <linux/bootmem.h>` in the code. When I run the code in Linux, I get the error

```
“fatal error: linux/bootmem.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/bootmem.h>”
```

How can I find that file? I searched and I could not find it.

If I find the file, how can I use it? Is putting the file in the same directory enough?

Comment: I believe that publishing your `Makefile` and a minimal code snippet which would fail will help us to troubleshoot the issue. As to "what to do" - you definitely should not copy the Linux headers to your sources directory once you find them on your system, instead, you have to point the compiler to the location where they are.

Comment: Is the code you are talking about in user or kernel space?

Comment: r u coding a kernel module?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/include/linux/bootmem.h) what you're looking for? If so, you can save it in a header file, say as bootmem.h and put it the directory together with you source code. Then use the following preprocessor directive:

#include "bootmem.h"

When you're including header files from System Libraries you use the "< >" brackets, when you're including a header file from a local folder you should use double quotation marks.